# PHP API Get Node

Tags: php, api

I am getting a API response as such:

```
"alert": "success",
"content": [
    {
        "id": "HIDDEN",
        "answers": {
            "3": {
                "text": "Name",
                "type": "control_textbox",
                "answer": "Tim"
            },
            "4": {
                "text": "Telephone Number",
                "type": "control_textbox",
                "answer": "Sample"
            }
   }
```

Whilst I can get "alert" for example I am not sure how to get each of the "TEXT" responses

I have tried this:

```
foreach ($submissions as $submissions) {
      print "<p class='list'><b>" . $submissions["alert"] . "</b><br>"; $answer['text'];

}
```

Just to be clear the code above is returning the ALERT content but not TEXT. I understand this is because it is in an array but I can't get that returned, nor can I find any responses similar to this in JotForm or find the answer by reading up on APIs!

Comment: loop through  `$submissions['content']['answer'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an associative array as the result, you can specify the second parameter for `json_decode()` as `TRUE:

```
$submissions = json_decode($yourJSONstring, TRUE);
```

Now, you'll have an associative array in `$submissions`. We just need to loop through the array:

```
foreach ($submissions['content'][0]['answers'] as $submission) {
    print $submission["text"]."<br/>"; 
}
```

Output:

```
Name
Telephone Number
```

Similarly, you can access other elements too.

[**See it live!**](http://codepad.org/Ry98mDDg)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how you are processing it, but if you use `$submission= json_decode($api_response, true);` you will get a multi-dimensional array, which you can loop through or access however you would like.

```
$submission["alert"] //"success"
$submission["content"]["answers"]["3"]["text"] //"name"
```